# How can I route certain traffic to a different access point ONLY when I'm connected to a certain network?

Tags: networking, wireless, bluetooth

I know this is pretty specific, but before I do anything, I want to make sure that what I want to do doesn't brick my system if all requirements aren't met.

I have a laptop. I take it to school with me every single day, and I play a game called Eyewire during lunch. Unfortunately, my schools wi-fi blocks the chat socket, so I cannot ask for help or talk to the other players, and I also get an annoying error message every 30 seconds saying that it can't connect to chat. What I want to do is make it so I can route the chat to my PAN connected via Bluetooth and have everything else run through the school wi-fi. I want it like this because the chat doesn't take up much data. If I routed everything through my phone, I would reach my data cap within the hour I have for lunch. Here's the information I have so far:

> Eyewire chat socket: ws://18.4.45.12:2569/chat
>
> Wireless device: wlan0
>
> Bluetooth device: bnep0

Is there a way I can make it so this only happens when my hotspot is on, and when I'm connected to my school wi-fi? I play this at home, and I don't want it to rely on my hotspot there as well.